# I want to refresh fragment on itemselect in spinner. But unfortunately not properly work

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code is given below.

```
 overview_spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new dapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedMonth=overview_spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();

                OverviewFragment over = new OverviewFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
              // Or: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .detach(over)
                        .attach(over)
                        .commit();
           }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: and what exactly is wrong? What is not properly?

Answer (score 0):

If so, detach the fragment and reattach it

```
// Reload current fragment
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Your_Fragment_TAG is the name you gave your fragment when you created it

This code is for support library.

If you're not supporting older devices, just use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager